# Wordpress gives 500 error on search results on different server

Tags: wordpress, windows, ubuntu, search, server

**Background**

We have developed a WordPress website on a staging server with a custom theme and a custom search.php to display the results. This worked like a charm with no errors or warnings in the log.

When the website was put on a different environment (Windows VM), the search results would give a 500 error.

**What have we've tried**

Since the search works on the staging and not on the live server, we have compared the server specs and PHP installs. These are results from a site check on the live server

```
Server architecture: Windows NT 10.0 AMD64
Web server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
PHP version: 7.2.18 (Supports 64bit values)
PHP SAPI: cgi-fcgi
PHP max input variables: 1000
PHP time limit: 300
PHP memory limit: 256M
Max input time: 60
Upload max filesize: 20M
PHP post max size: 8M
cURL version: 7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1b
Is SUHOSIN installed?: No
Is the Imagick library available?: No
```

This is the staging server:

```
Server architecture: Linux 4.19.8-x86_64-linode120 x86_64
Web server: nginx/1.13.6
PHP version: 7.3.2 (Supports 64bit values)
PHP SAPI: fpm-fcgi
PHP max input variables: 3000
PHP time limit: 120
PHP memory limit: 256M
Max input time: 60
Upload max filesize: 64M
PHP post max size: 64M
cURL version: 7.60.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e
Is SUHOSIN installed?: No
Is the Imagick library available?: Yes
.htaccess rules Custom rules have been added to your .htaccess file.
```

The PHP version is recently set to 7.3 on the staging server for testing purposes. I have also checked if all required PHP components are installed on the live server, and that's the case.

**Question**

What do you suggest I try next? PHP version 7.2 or 7.3 doesn't seem to be the issue, the big difference I see is that maybe it's not working because it's on a Windows server, but the rest of the website works fine.

Comment: and where's the code that triggers the 500?

Comment: Check server log or set `wp_debug=true` on your`wp-config.php` file

Answer (score 0):

The error is found. I've used short PHP opening '' at one point and that wasn't configured on the new server in the php.ini.